# Netbeans source code font not being well rendered

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, netbeans-11, font-rendering

I'm having an issue using Netbeans under Linux, I'm using Arch Linux with KDE and JRE 8 and, as you can see from the screenshot, the GUI fonts are ok, but the source code font rendering is very ugly. I'm using java options for AA, but it only solved the GUI issue, not the source code font rendering issue. I have PHPStorm installed too, to compare, I made a screenshot using the same font and settings in both. PHPStorm fonts are rendered beautifully, Netbeans doesn't, what's the problem?

[image]

Comment: Hah, this is one of the rare occasions when a screenshot of code from your IDE is actually appropriate.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica thank you. I simply don't know why java is so messy with font rendering in Linux and I don't understand why Netbeans is so inconsistent with font rendering. If all fonts in other Netbeans windows are ok and beautifully rendered, why the source code window renders fonts in a different way? I like Netbeans, but it renders source code fonts as if we were seeing 90's consoles...

Comment: If you want to solve this by programming, you need to show your code ... As it is, this may better be on topic at [unix.se].

Comment: [1] What *specifically* concerns you about the font rendering of the source code in NetBeans? The rendering in your screen shot looks acceptable to me. I guess I'm just not understanding what is bothering you. Is the problem that the rendering in the _Preview_ window differs from that in the actual edit window? [2] Perhaps your issue is specific to _FlatLaf Dark_; do you see the same issue(s) with _FlatLaf Light_? [3] Alternatively, what happens if you choose a different font? Is the issue specific to _Ubuntu Mono_?

Comment: @skomisa if you compare the font rendering in PHPStorm the font is more well designed than it is in Netbeans. I chose the same font, same font size for both, so why Netbeans renders fonts differently? this difference that bothers me. The font in Netbeans is ugly, in PHPStorm looks like more fluid. And this difference in font rendering happens whatever font I choose.

Comment: @usr2564301 this code is a random code just to show the differences in font rendering between PHPStorm and Netbeans, it's not a code I'm working on to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could check, forcing PHPStorm to use the Oracle JDK, what makes font rendering different between Netbeans and PHPStorm is the JRE being used. When I forced PHPStorm to use the Oracle JDK it rendered fonts exactly the same way Netbeans renders. So JetBrains, with it's own JRE, were managed to make a JRE that renders fonts better than OpenJDK or OracleJDK.

[image]